# Why flask application is taking so long to run?

Tags: python, flask, topic-modeling, python-newspaper

This is my home page and it takes 30 seconds to run. There are lot of graphs, wordcloud based on the dataset that have approx 1000 articles and some basic operation on sqlalchemy. But still it should not take that much time. How can I reduce the time?

```
@app.route('/home',methods=["get","post"])
def showjson():
    folder = 'C:/Users/Mansi Dhingra/Desktop/Projects/api/news/static/images'
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
        os.remove(file_path)

    news_df = pd.read_csv('news_information1.csv')
    news_df.to_sql('users', con=engine)
    topic_l = engine.execute('''Select distinct Topic from users''').fetchall()
    topic_list=[]
    for tr in topic_l:
        topic_list.append(tr[0])
    search = request.form.get("search")
    source_l=engine.execute('''Select distinct source from users''').fetchall()
    source_list = []
    for tr in source_l:
        source_list.append(tr[0])
    bank_l = engine.execute('''Select distinct bank from users''').fetchall()
    bank_list = []
    for tr in bank_l:
        bank_list.append(tr[0])
    end_date = engine.execute('''Select max(date) from users''').fetchall()

    max_date=end_date[0][0]
    sent_count = engine.execute('''Select Sentiment,Count(*) from users group by Sentiment''').fetchall()
    sent_topic = []
    sent_count1 = []
    for tx in sent_count:
        sent_topic.append(tx[0])
        sent_count1.append(tx[1])
    fig_sent=create_graphs(sent_topic,sent_count1,"sentiment")
    list_words = fetch_sentiment_using_vader(news_df['clean_text'])
    stopwords = stopwords_for_wordcount(news_df['clean_text'])
    count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words=stopwords[0])
    fig_pos=plot_words(list_words[0], list_words[2], "positive")
    fig_neg=plot_words(list_words[1], list_words[2], "negative")
    fig_cat=count_category(news_df)
    fig_pub=count_pub(news_df)
    create_wordcloud( stopwords)
    fig_tri=bigram_or_trigram(news_df['clean_text'], stopwords,"bigram")
    images_list = os.listdir(os.path.join(app.static_folder, "images"))
    return render_template('news_home.html',fig_pub=fig_pub,topic_list=topic_list,img=images_list,plt_pos=fig_pos,plt_tri=fig_tri,plt_neg=fig_neg,
                           bank_list=bank_list,source_list=source_list,max_date=max_date,fig_cat=fig_cat,fig_sent=fig_sent,search=search)
```

Comment: Profile it. See where it is spending its time.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: This looks like a good tool. github.com/muatik/flask-profiler

Answer (score 0):

If you're using older than 1.0 version of Flask, then enable multi-threading. e.g. `app.run(threaded=True)`. Otherwise, if you have version newer than 1.0 then you can use Flask's default WSGI toolkit Werkzeug profiler to find expensive functions for each request.

```py
from werkzeug.middleware.profiler import ProfilerMiddleware
app = ProfilerMiddleware(app, restrictions=[20])
```

Doing above will show the 20 most expensive functions for each request. Inspect them and modify/refactor yourself.

Just a tip if you're considering taking it to production, default Flask isn't production-ready. There are a few additional steps to take a flask app to production. Some guidance here in the official Flask documentation: [Deploy to Production](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/deploy/). [Gunicorn with NGINX](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/wsgi-standalone/) is a very good option.